# How to use digit separators for Python integer literals?

Tags: python, literals

Is there any way to group digits in a Python code to increase code legibility? I've tried `'` and `_` which are [*digit separators*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_literal#Digit_separators) of some other languages, but no avail.

A weird operator which concatenates its left hand side with its right hand side could also work out.

Comment: can you be more specific.. give an example?

Comment: I think he wants to replace the integer literal 31415926 with 31_415_926, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure that's implemented. There are proposals, but not implementations

Comment: `int('100,000'.replace(',', ''))` is ok?

Comment: Guido mentioned this in this years pycon keynote https://youtu.be/YgtL4S7Hrwo?t=428, its coming in 3.6

Comment: I though that the link would be enough to make it clear. Example that Prune gave fits perfectly.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Update a few years later: Python 3.6 now supports [PEP515](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/#literal-grammar), and so you can use _ for float and integer literal readability improvement.

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1_1000
11000
>>>
```

For historical reference, you can look at the lexical analysis for strict definitions [python2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#numeric-literals), [python3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#numeric-literals) ...

For python3.6.0a2 and earlier, you should get an error message similar to:

```
Python 3.6.0a2 (v3.6.0a2:378893423552, Jun 13 2016, 14:44:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1_000
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1_000
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> amount = 10_000_000.0
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    amount = 10_000_000.0
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 5):

Currently there is no thousands separator in Python, but you can use `locale` module to convert string with such separators to an int:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
locale.atoi("1,000,000")
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such function in Python but it was proposed to integrate it in the future.

You can see the proposal in the [PEP515](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/).

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I've seen in python is `12 * 1000 * 1000`, which is not ideal, but can be useful if `12000000` is needed. Be advised though, while in C, those are equivalent, because at compile time it converts both to the same thing, python may not share this optimization.

Comment: If they are literals, python will fold the constants.  It won't do any folding of symbols though.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would, but I didn't want to spread bad info.

Comment: For 12 million, I'd use and recommend `12e6`.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin -- Well, that depends on whether you want your value to be a `float` or an `int`...

Comment: @TemporalWolf -- You can always check these things by disassembling the source: `dis.dis(lambda : 100 * 200 * 300)`

Comment: @mgilson: As it happens, this is one of those things where order matters a lot. If you use `x * 100 * 1000 * 1000`, then it won't fold (because `x * 100` might not return an `int` if `x` isn't an `int`). But `100 * 1000 * 1000 * x` folds, because the left to right evaluation is working with known constants.