# Declaring a number in Python. Possible to emphasize thousand?

Tags: python, numbers, clarity

Is it possible to declare a number in Python as

```
a = 35_000
a = 35,000
```

Neither seem to work of course. How do you emphasize things like these, for clarity in Python? Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use digit separators for Python integer literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155177/how-to-use-digit-separators-for-python-integer-literals)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually [just now possible](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep515) in Python 3.6.

You can use the first format that you showed:

```
a = 35_000
```

because underscores are now an accepted separator in numbers. (You could even say `a = 3_5_00_0`, though why would you?)

The second method you showed will actually create a tuple. It's the same as saying:

```
a = (35, 000)  # Which is also the same as (35, 0).
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible [starting with python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep515).

> PEP 515 adds the ability to use underscores in numeric literals for improved readability. For example:
>
> ```
> >>> 1_000_000_000_000_000
> 1000000000000000
> >>> 0x_FF_FF_FF_FF
> 4294967295
> ```