# What do 1_000 and 100_000 mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Since I've been learning Python, I've sometimes seen beginner examples that look like this:

```
sum_sq = [None] * 1_000
```

I've bought three Python books and none have mentioned what the `1_000` and `100_000` means that I'm seeing in these examples.

My question is: is `1_000` the same as 1,000? And if so, why do they write it as `1_000`? Does it have a special function that 1,000 does not? Things like:

```
if __name__ == __main__
```

have sensible reasons for using the underscore and I can't see a reason why `1_000` is used.

Comment: Strongly related (not sure if duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/43817634/4909087

Comment: The cool thing about python is that you can open up an interpreter and try things out. So what happens if you do `1000 == 1_000`?

Comment: Paul H - yeah I got "true" when I tested your example in Idle, and the example I was trying ran the same regardless of whether I used 1,000 or 1_000. But I'm only using basic code, so I wondered if it made a difference in more complicated examples with greater complexity of time/efficiency. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

These are allowed since Python 3.6, see [PEP 515 - Underscores in Numeric Literals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/). As stated in the PEP

> The underscores have no semantic meaning, and literals are parsed as if the underscores were absent.

So they are just available for readability for large numbers, binary literals, hex addresses, etc. Some examples from the PEP:

```
>>> assert 10_000_000 == 10000000

>>> assert 0xCAFE_F00D == 0xCAFEF00D

>>> assert 0b_0011_1111_0100_1110 == 0b0011111101001110
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's the same as without the underscores. They have underscores there to act as thousand seperators, which for longer numbers can make them easier to read.

It's similar to how in writing we separate thousands with commas (or dots depending on your region):

```
1,000,000 # A million
```

Because of how that would interfere with tuple creation though:

```
n = 1,000,000
print(type(n))

<class 'tuple'>
```

Python uses underscores instead of commas.

Comment: "normal life" ... indeed, developers lead very abnormal lives :p

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I sat there for a couple seconds searching for the right word. Whenever I start talking about programming to most people, they look at me like I'm speaking Greek, so "normal" seemed appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. I spent some time in Italy and noticed they write 1000 as 1.000 which is very confusing as it looks like 1 Euro instead of a thousand. But I'd never seen 1_000 before. You're right - it would make a very long number easier to read.

Comment: @Shaken_not_stirred. Np. Ya, the . and , differences can be confusing. In North America (Canada specifically), we only use commas, which I prefer. And just an FYI, you can use scientific notation to write numbers to make them easier to read as well. A million can alternatively be written as `1e6` (1 x 10^6). That way, you don't have to count zeros.

Comment: Carcigenicate - thank you. The 1e6 format would definitely be my preference so I'll use that.