# Python: Write code with large numbers readable in EDITOR

Tags: python

I can see multiple pages explaining how to format and print numbers in python, but is there a way to write code with large numbers in a readable way?

```
speed_of_light = 299 792 458       # metres
dist_to_andromeda = 2,537,497      # light years
dia_of_earth_at_eq = 12_756_320    # metres
```

**EDIT**: I found the last one working on py36, but what's the solution for those using py35? Isn't there a way other than comments which would be redundant?

Comment: may be treat them as string, and convert to numbers on computation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Digit separators in Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155177/digit-separators-in-python-code)

Comment: @yosemite_k I would rather type that as a comment rather than to have the interpreter see it and process the same!

Comment: As noted in the duplicate, with python 3.6, use _ (as in your third example); for python < 3.6, you're stuck with less ideal workarounds

Answer (score 2):

From Python 3.6 there is

```
dia_of_earth_at_eq = 12_756_320
```

Is valid code.

See [PEP 515: Underscores in Numeric Literals in What's new in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-515-underscores-in-numeric-literals)

Comment: i actually tried it! But in 3.5.x... :/ So there's no way other than parsing strings and comments for 3.5?

Comment: You can use comments `dia_of_earth_at_eq = 12756320  # 12_756_320 metres` for it to be more readable

Comment: Looks like there's no cleaner way...! :(